# How to add dynamically textview..?

Tags: android

I have this code in android and I want to display the value of both username and password. I already used the setcontentview but it only display one of the textview. Can someone help me??

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.MESSAGE);
    String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.MESSAGE2);


    TextView username = new TextView(this);
    TextView password = new TextView(this);
    username.setText(message);
    password.setText(message2);
```

Comment: create a linearlayout or relativelayout add textviews as child to the same. Then setContentView(linearlayout or relativelayout);

Answer (score 0):

You have to set two more

```
username.setId(5);// 5 is id
username.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

and add it to your layout. Note that this is the `LinearLayout` in your xml file and you have to add the textview to it.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.info)
linearLayout.addView(username);
```

Do the same for password

Answer (score 0):

Create the textviews in xml inside linearlayout or relativelayout as required and then 
set text.

For example: If your textview 1 is having id `textview1` defined in xml as

> android:id="@+id/textview1"

Then in your code do -

```
TextView mytextview1= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
```

Similarly,

If your textview 2 is having id `textview2` defined in xml as

> android:id="@+id/textview2"

.

Then in your code do:

```
TextView mytextview2= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview2);
```

Then simply do:

```
mytextview1.setText(message);
mytextview2.setText(message2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below:

```
 LinearLayout m_vwJokeLayout=(LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.m_vwJokeLayout); 
LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 TextView tvUsername=new TextView(this);
 tvUsername.setLayoutParams(lparams);
 tvUsername.setText("UserName");
 this.m_vwJokeLayout.addView(tvUsername);  

 TextView tvPassword=new TextView(this);
 tvPassword.setLayoutParams(lparams);
 tvPassword.setText("Password");
  this.m_vwJokeLayout.addView(tvPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to add two textviews dynamically to your layout...Heres a code for it

//code for main file

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout container=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

        //adding the first textview
        TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText("TextView1");

        TextView tv2=new TextView(this);
        tv2.setText("TextView2");

        container.addView(tv1);
        container.addView(tv2);

    }



}
```

//the layout file

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps you